# SQL query to get an id

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a table **country** that is represented in the following format

```
id name
1   at
2   be
3   ch
...
```

I am trying to perform a query where I can get the list of all the id values, by using the WHERE clause on the name columns

```
var countryIDQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `country` WHERE `name` = ?";

connection.query(countryIDQuery, countriesObj , function (err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.error("Country Table Error:", err.stack);
    }
    console.log(result);

});
```

The `countriesObj` represents the array of all the countries, but the only result I see is for the first row of id = 1

Comment: What exactly is the result of the query supposed to look like? If you are after all of the `id` values from the `country` table, then you wouldn't require the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use *IN*.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `country` WHERE `name` IN (?)
```

if your *connection* object does not support arrays, then

```
var queryList = [];
for (var country in countriesObj) {
    queryList.push("?");
}
var countryIDQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `country` WHERE `name` IN ("+queryList.join(",")+")";

connection.query(countryIDQuery, countriesObj , function (err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.error("Country Table Error:", err.stack);
    }
    console.log(result);

});
```

Alternatively, if it does support arrays then

```
var countryIDQuery = "SELECT `id` FROM `country` WHERE `name` IN (?)";

connection.query(countryIDQuery, [countriesObj] , function (err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.error("Country Table Error:", err.stack);
    }
    console.log(result);

});
```

Comment: would it be (SELECT `id` FROM `country` WHERE `name` IN (?), countriesObj, function(){}). 

This seems to be returning an undefined result

Comment: not sure what your 'connection' object is, but if your second parameter does not support arrays you could use a loop to append '?' and use the countriesObj array directly. I'll update the answer for you.